# C++ Pointers - When do they get reassigned?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have the following code to demonstrate my question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    queue<int> numbers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }

    int temp = 10;
    int *last = &temp;

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << *last << endl;
        int i = numbers.front();
        cout << *last << endl << endl;

        numbers.pop();
        last = &i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which will print out:

```
10
10

0
1

1
2

2
3

3
4

4
5

5
6

6
7

7
8

8
9
```

I have some confusion on why the pointer `last` is being reassigned whenever `int i` changes. What I want is for for `last` to hold a reference to the last element - but am having trouble. I would guess that the pointer is pointing to the value of `i` - and changes when `i` changes. But `i` is inside the scope of the for loop, so I'm not exactly sure whats going on here.

Comment: ...because: `last = &i;` I don't think you want to use pointers here. Just store the last number as an int.

Comment: *hold a reference to the last element*  -- That `&` is not a reference.  In this context it means `address-of`.  Maybe that is your confusion -- say out loud what that symbol means, and maybe it will be clearer to you.

Comment: I'd be slightly suspicious of taking the address of i, a variable on the stack.  It may be just coincidence that the pointer is still pointing to the previous value (instead of having been overwritten).

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Though the program works because the address of local variable i is not being changed nevertheless the program has undefined behaviour becuase in each iteration of the loop except the first iteration pointer last refers to non alive object in statement

```
cout << *last << endl;
```

due to the assignment

```
last = &i;
```

A correct loop could look the following way

```
   for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << *last << endl;
        int i = numbers.front();
        cout << *last << endl << endl;

        numbers.pop();
        *last = i;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```